# How can I solve the issue: psql cannot connect to the server in Ubuntu?

Tags: django, postgresql, vps

In hosting my Django web application on VPS using PostgreSQl. However, the configuration seems to be fine but whenever I want to access the Postgres Shell, I ma getting the error bellow.

```
root@vmi851374:~# sudo su -l postgres
        postgres@vmi851374:~$ psql
        psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
                Is the server running locally and accepting
                connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
        postgres@vmi851374:~$
```

[image]
I have checked the Postgres service status and everything seems fine but I don't know where this error comes from. Notice that in my localhost (laptop), I am not facing this issue. Only in the VPS server, I am getting this issue.

Please assist me to solve this issue.

[image]

Comment: Look in the db servers log file.

Comment: Assuming you are on Ubuntu/Debian try `pg_lscluster` or `sudo systemctl status postgresql@<version>-main.service` where `<version>` is the Postgres version. `postgresql` in `... status postgresql` refers to bootstrap process that launches the actual server or servers and then exits. `postgresql@<version>-main.service` is the actual server process.

Comment: Dear Mr @AdrianKlaver, could you please divide you solution into steps. Like this I am not able to organize the steps how to follow. Please notice that I'm using ubuntu 20.04. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem by editing the file `postgresql.conf` located in `/etc/postgresql/14/main/postgresql.conf`
Then I uncommented and edit the listen_addresses attribute to start listening to start listening to all available IP addresses: `listen_addresses = '*'`

In addition I edited the PostgreSQL access policy configuration file as follow:

```
vim /etc/postgresql/14/main/pg_hba.conf.
```

Then I modified the file as follow:

```
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

And now it is working fine. Thanks a lot @AdrianKlaver

Answer (score 1):

Doing:

`sudo systemctl status postgresql.service`

just shows whether the status of the bootstrap process `postgresql.service` ran. This process is used to start the actual Postgres server or servers.

To see whether the actual servers are running do:

`pg_lsclusters`

This will show the status of the server(s).

Another option is to to use:

`sudo systemctl status postgresql@<version>-main.service`

where you replace `<version>` with the version number of the Postgres server.

Comment: By running the pg_lsclusters  command , here is the output:  9.6 main    5444 down   postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.6-main.log.

Comment: Mr @AdrianKlaver, the status is down.

Comment: Then do: `sudo systemctl start postgresql.service`.

Comment: The status does not change. Its still show status down

Comment: What does `pg_lsclusters` show?

Comment: at the new attachment, please. I have edited the question

Comment: **Do not** use images for textual data, copy and paste text from the console into your question.

Comment: Also you need to learn to read the error messages, they tell you what is going on. I would copy and paste the relevant part, but I can't since it is an image. Short version something else is using port 5444. Run `ps ax | grep post` to see if it is another Postgres instance. If there is not another Postgres instance running then do: `sudo lsof -i tcp:5444` to see what is using that port.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244117/discussion-between-mohamed-abdillah-and-adrian-klaver).